# For some reason all the modifier alignment are being neglected when i call a Method inside of another Method in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

So I was learning android dev and came across this thing. Whenever I call a Method inside of another Method all of its alignments and arrangements are being neglected and the ui elements stays in their default aligment.

```
@Composable
fun HappyBirthday(message: String,form: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
        Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, modifier = modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            ) {
            Text(
                text = message,
                modifier = Modifier,
                fontSize = 100.sp,
                lineHeight = 116.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
            Text(
                text = form,
                fontSize = 36.sp,
                modifier = modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .align(alignment = Alignment.End)
            )
        }
}
@Composable
fun BirthdayImage(message: String,from: String,modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    Box {
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = null
        )
        HappyBirthday(
            message = message,
            form = from,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
}

@Preview(name = "Cool", showSystemUi = true,showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun BirthdayCardPreview() {
    BirthdayCardTheme {
        BirthdayImage(message = "Happy Birthday Sam", from = "From Smith")
    }
}
```

The picture on the left is what I'm getting and on the right is what I'm supposed to get.
[image: Output I'm getting]
[image: Outpust I'm supposed to get]

Comment: in the second ```Text``` in the column use ```Modifier```, instead of ```modifier```